# Drawing Lines At Crossover Points with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, line, grayscale

I am now making a program with OpenCV which should have these features:

1. Drawing lines on a white canvas;
2. The color of every line is **grayscale, that is, I use CV_8UC1**;
3. If a line being drawing is crossing over other lines, the grayscale at the crossover points is calculated as:

   ```
   grayscaleResult = 0.5 * ( grayscaleOld + grayscaleNew);
   ```

where `grayscaleOld` is the color of lines which have been drawn on canvas and
      `grayscaleNew` is the color of line which has been drawn.

4.**The thickness of lines may not be 1, sometimes > 1.**

I want to know how to draw points at crossover points, and the most difficult for me is the thinness of lines is not the same.

Comment: `The thinness of lines may not be 1, sometimes > 1` Ok, then if it can't be 1 and if its only **sometimes** >1, in the other cases, what's the width value ? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For drawing line, [the manual](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=line#line) says it all, for example:

```
int thickness = (a value above 0);
cv::line( image, cv::Point(x0,y0), cv::Point(x1,y1), cv::Scalar(10,20,30), thickness ),
```

Please not that the color is given here in the order B,G,R. If you have a single channel image, only the first value will be used.